# Linq to SQL: Ammend command before submission to database

Tags: linq-to-sql, .net-3.5, ado.net, change-tracking, sqlclient

Is there a hook somewhere within Linq to SQL that would allow me to manually modify a command before it is sent to the database?

Specifically, I am trying to introduce the [`WITH CHANGE_TRACKING_CONTEXT(@contextData)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895330.aspx) syntax whenever an insert/update/delete is applied to the database in order to be able to add additional information against the change tracking, such as the user who instigated the change (this is a web application that uses SQL Authentication).

This syntax will simply need to be inserted at the beginning of the CommandText, along with an additional parameter `(@contextData)` being added to the SqlCommand object which will contain the data for the additional statement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI - I updated my answer below with some alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to alter any SQL... just supply your DataContext with an existing SqlConnection.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386986.aspx

Before submitting changes via [DataContext.SubmitChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.submitchanges.aspx), create your own SqlCommand (using the same SqlConnection you created your DataContext with) for the `WITH CHANGE_TRACKING_CONTEXT` command and execute it. That statement will be valid for the duration of the database connection.

**UPDATE:**
Since that didn't work, and if doing change tracking manually isn't an option (via [DataContext.GetChangeSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.getchangeset.aspx) which is what I do on my current app), I think you're going to be stuck doing just about the ugliest thing possible: [specify the SQL statements for all of your INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE through partial methods on your DataContext](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/27/linq-to-sql-part-8-executing-custom-sql-expressions.aspx) (last section). Or even uglier, use [DataContext.Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log.aspx) to log all the SQL generated, execute the SubmitChanges in a Transaction, roll it back, then modify the SQL you get out of the log and execute it as desired.

Comment: I like this idea. I will have to see if I can inject this into the SubmitChanges chain via inheritance. Will let you know how I get on.
Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, issuing the statement on its own, without the subsequent update command for example, results in an error.
I will have to find a way of inserting it into the actual update commands. Thanks anyway.